# Applying find query on mongo from pyspark

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to query mongo db using a find operation instead of loading the entire collection and then applying pyspark filters which is mentioned in most of the documentation. Is there any way to do this?

I am looking for something to query mongo, rather than loading the entire mongo collection into pyspark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the option of "pipeline"

```
df = spark.read \
    .format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource") \
    .option("uri", "mongodb://<host>:<port>/<database>.<collection>") \
    .option("aggregation.pipeline", "[{'$match': {<query>}}]") \
    .load()
```

Comment: @Buzz, Thanks for your answer,
For me option("pipeline", "") worked too, do we get any additional functionalities by using aggregation.pipeline?

Comment: The docs (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/current/configuration/read/) say `aggregation.pipeline`.   For me, on connector version 10.0.1, `pipeline` is ignored.

Comment: Please add an explanation of what does the aggregation pipeline does.